VB.NET Call a programmatically made label from another form
I programmatically create a label on form1 and want to call it on form2.
The follow i tryed.
On form1:
Dim lblAnimation As New Label

Me.Controls.Add(lblAnimation)

On form2
form1.lblAnimation.text = "Test"

But the part on form2 is not working.
I hope anyone can help. Thanx
I hope some can help me with the richt code.

Please don't post unformatted code snippets. If you don't know how to format your post, spend some time in the Help Center to learn. Making your question as readable as possible is a requirement. You need to do all that you can to help us help you.

For the record, I downvoted this question because there is a load of information on the web, including this site, about accessing controls created at run time but, based on your question, you haven't made the effort to look at any of it. A lack of research is a specific reason for down-voting. Asking new questions on sites like this should be your last resort, not your first option.

Do these answer your question? How to pass value of a label from one form to another form in VB.NET? Or How to update text in the label in another form in VB.NET when both form are active (Message Passing) or .. modify label in form1 from form2.

You don't "call" a Label, or any other object for that matter. You call a method.
In theory, you can access that Label via the very same Controls collection of the form that you added it to. You could access it by Name, but you haven't set one. You could access it by index if you know what that is, e.g.
Dim lbl = DirectCast(Form1.Controls(labelIndex), Label)

I'm guessing that you don't know what the index is though. Another option would be to loop over the controls in that collection and identify the one you want by some other property(ies), e.g.
For Each lbl In Fomr1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    If lbl.SomeProperty = someValue Then
        'This is the Label you want.
    End If
Next

All of this is very dodgy though, and you should not do any of it. What you should actually do is write a method in Form1 that does what you need to do with that Label and then call that method from your other form. That other form should not even need to know that the Label exists. It should simply pass the appropriate data to the method and let Form1 look after itself, e.g.
Public Sub DisplayInLabel(text As String)
    Controls(labelIndex).Text = text
End Sub

Also, why exactly are you creating this Label in code in the first place? Can there be multiple Labels added and you won't know how many beforehand? If so, you're going to have to work out how to distinguish them and get just the one you need. If that's not the case, why not just add the Label to the form in the designer and set its Visible property to False, then call its Show method to you want the user to see it? Then you can just access it like you would any other Label, e.g.
Public Sub DisplayInAnimationLabel(text As String)
    animationLabel.Text = text
End Sub

I should also add that the most appropriate option depends on the relationship between the form containing the Label and the code that wants to change it. If, for instance, that code is in a form that is opened by the form containing the Label, the most appropriate option would be for the second to form to raise an event and for the first form to handle that event. That way, the second form doesn't even need to know that the first form exists, never mind the Label. The more you can decouple types like this, the better.
